# Windows 10 power options missing on new laptop

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, power-options

I have two Dell Latitude laptops with Windows 10.
An old one and a new one I just got.

On the new laptop when I open Power Options --> Advanced settings, I only see the following groups: "Desktop background settings", Sleep, "Power buttons and lid", Display, Battery.

However, on my other laptop with win10 enterprise, I have all these plus a lot more, like: Hard disk, Internet Explorer, USB settings, Intel Graphics settings, Processor Management, etc. How do I get those on the new one?

The new one has a Dell Power Management app installed. That seems to be a battery driver. Could that be the one that's interfering?

I have a screenshot of the two different *Power Options* windows here:

[image: Left is the new laptop with limited options. Right is the old one with full set of options.]

The left is the new laptop with limited options and the right is the old one with full set of options.

Comment: Try removing Dell Power Management. Then restart and test. I am looking at a couple of recent laptops here and Power Options are fully laid out. Dell Power Management is not the Power Driver. Try also updating BIOS and the Power Driver

Comment: Where/what is the Power Driver?

Comment: Look in the Dell Support site for your machine and there will be a power driver (and BIOS) for your laptop.

Comment: I have now uninstalled Dell Power Manager and rebooted. I also uninstalled Dell Power Manager Service (there were two apps installed). This did not solve the problem. I still only have limited power options on the new laptop.

Comment: Please note that the screenshot does show "Change settings that are currently unavailable". I have, of course, tried clicking this. It does not reveal any more settings to change.

Comment: You should download and run (it's standalone, doesn't require install) a freeware called Power Settings Explorer (here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/wt37sbsejk7iepm/PowerSettingsExplorer.zip). I use it myself on new PCs where those power management options are often missing, or hidden, more like. Gives you many options on how to customize your power plans.

Comment: Also ask Dell Support about this. Third party stuff is fine, but there should not be a need to use it to make the machine work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem here:
https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000211304-How-to-disable-power-throttling-on-Windows

It is because the system is configured to use Connected Standby as the sleep mode (Connected Standby is similar to how smartphones work: they go into a low-power mode, but there is still some processing possible).

The solution is to disable connected standby. Here's how (only for Windows 10 versions below 2004):

1. Type regedit to open Registry Editor.
2. Go to
   “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power“
3. Double click on “CsEnabled”
4. Change Value data from “1″ to “0″
5. Click OK.
6. Restart your computer to apply these changes to your system.

Maybe there is an easier (non-regedit) way of doing this. However, I have not been able to find it.

Comment: Happened to me on  new HP envy with WIN10 /1909. USB HD was always disconnecting and nowhere to change that behavior. you saved my day.

Comment: I can't find "CsEnabled" under Power

Answer (score 18):

Launch your registry editor and navigate to \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings.

If you expand all of the sub-folders, click on any one of them, and you'll see a "Description" and a "Friendly Name" that describe which advanced power setting option they control.  Scroll through, read those descriptions, and find the settings that you want to be able to control in advanced power settings.

For each of these, find the "Attributes" REG_DWORD file and change its value to the number 2.  That setting will now show up in and can be controlled from your advanced power settings.

If you come across a setting that lacks the "Attributes" file, just create a new DWORD file called "Attributes" in that folder, set the value to 2, and it'll likewise show up in your advanced power settings.

It's a bit tedious to scroll through ~100 options, but I was able to fully-customize my advanced power settings interface in about 30 minutes.

Comment: Life saver! this worked for me perfectly and its good to know where the options are and how to manually turn them on.

Answer (score 1):

Really wanted to emphasize on the comment by user1019780. I was about to skip trying it out, but later it turned out to be the only one that worked for me. So, adding it as an answer. (For some reason even editing the values via registry editor didn't work for me. Maybe I messed it up somewhere!)

> You should download and run (it's standalone, doesn't require install) a freeware called Power Settings Explorer. I use it myself on new PCs where those power management options are often missing, or hidden, more like. Gives you many options on how to customize your power plans.

Edit:-
The above mentioned utility tool is a community built software. You can download or read more about it from this [post](https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/windows-power-plan-settings-explorer-utility.416058/).

Comment: Downloading some random executable from mediafire is NOT a good solution to anything.