# Power button does not wake when connected to docking station

Tags: windows, laptop, usb, sleep, wake-up

(Just documenting for others with the same problem:) For some time my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T480) did exhibit this strange problem when trying to resume from Sleep/Hibernate:

- When the laptop was connected to a USB-C dock (on AC) the laptop would **not wake** when pressing the power button. Rather the power button would just blink rapidly three times (which the Lenovo docs say is just indicative of a AC adapter being connected).
- When the laptop was disconnected (on battery) then the power button would **wake** as usual.

Things I tried unsuccessfully to resolve:

- Look for any BIOS boot/start option referring to power button or boot/wake functions.
- Check in the device manager that devices such as the keyboard were marked as "Allow this device to wake up the computer"

Answer (score 2):

I have recently faced the same issue, on lenovo x1c laptop and wavlink thunderbolt dock.

I have tried all the solutions listed here and these alone didn't do the trick. When the laptop was off and I would press the power button on the dock, the power button light on the laptop just blinked 3x, just as you described.

This was a good sign because it meant that the dock is simulating a power cycle when pressing the button. I went into bios and enabled wake on AC. Boom like magic the dock power button turned on my laptop.

- laptop display is disabled
- laptop lid is closed/ set to do nothing when plugged in
- i made sure to follow all of the dock manufacturers instructions including uninstalling previous displaylink versions using a clean up tool, reboot, installing latest displaylink drivers, connecting dock to power, turning it on, and only then connecting it
  -I also followed all the steps mentioned by other users
- - disable "USB selective suspend settings"
- -- ^that^ was not visible for me so I followed another step to enable this setting: https://superuser.com/a/1600223/628977

Not sure if all of the steps contributed to the dock finally working as intended, (they might have).The bios setting is the last thing I did before it started to work.

Finally, this thread also helped me troubleshoot https://community.frame.work/t/12th-gen-wont-wake-up-from-dock-power-on-button/21394

Total time from unboxing to having it up and running, including troubleshooting and research was like 30mins. Hope this helps, Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To get the power button to work with the docking station I needed to disable "USB selective suspend settings" (Windows > Edit Power Plan > Changed Advanced Power Settings > USB Settings > Plugged in > **Disable**).

[image: Disable USB suspend settings]

If the entry for selective suspend is missing [you can follow this superuser answer to enable it](https://superuser.com/a/1600223/628977).

Comment: In my W10 (21H2) the USB option does not show up there for some reason. I have there just "desktop background settings", "energy savings", "display and "battery", but no "USB" section. https://i.imgur.com/m4yAkJU.png

Comment: I am still on 21H1 so I can't say, but it might be an option which is disabled in the HP Power Plan. You might try to unhide the settings following https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/usb-settings-in-power-plan-options-on-windows-10/38753b89-65d0-49c1-8f91-2bb50f9b19a0

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this, but it did not help. On another W10 PC with 21H2 everything shows up as it should.

Comment: This helped to enable the USB options and after that I was able to fix the power button issue as you described: https://superuser.com/a/1600223/628977

Comment: I added your suggestion to the answer. An upvote would be welcome to indicate the answers works for others.