# Why can’t I control my power plan but instead get an enterprise message “…managed by your organization.” on my home computer

Tags: windows-10, bios, administrator

After a 20 day uptime with a few needed updates I did a reboot. Did a BIOS update while anyways rebooting. Later after using it for a while and leaving it idle I come back and found my computer in sleep mode.

This had happened before after installing some app that added a power scheme so I assumed same thing happened again and went to change to my power scheme. But to my surprise I see the buttons are grayed out and a message saying:

> “Some of these settings are hidden or managed by your organization.”

I’ve seen this at work but this is a single PC running Windows 10 Pro home network computer built from scratch. No enterprise. I cannot find anything else with the same lock and message. I have really looked through my BIOS and there really seem to be no setting that can mess with this. Also same error in safe-mode admin.

How can I get rid of this? Can I trace the block somehow?

[image]

Comment: Try it while booting in Safe mode.

Comment: I did mention it's the same thing in safe-mode admin

Comment: Do you see anything that got installed recently enough in *Control Panel > Programs and Features*? If nothing was installed and System restore is enabled, you could rollback to a time before it happened.

Comment: @harrymc nope nothing just updates of Chrome and Spotify

Comment: Is System restore an option?

Comment: Nope no restore points hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`), navigate to
*Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management*
and ensure that "Specify a custom active power plan policy" is set to Disabled.

You could in CMD that is run as Administrator enter the command
`powercfg -restoredefaultschemes`.

Comment: You are my saviour! Posted on so many forums no one figured it out. Sadly I ran both fixes and rebooted so don't know what fixed it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Since it's Windows 10 Pro, you have access to the [Group Policy Editor](https://techdirectarchive.com/2020/03/30/how-to-disable-power-plan-in-windows-via-gpo-and-windows-settings/). Just *undo* any changes that prevent individual management of Power Options.

This can also be done through Regedit, for those with Windows 10 Home. [Check that](https://superuser.com/questions/1536904/windows-10-power-options-missing-on-new-laptop) `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power` does not have a value, `CsEnabled`, set to `1`. If so, set it to `0`. See also [Microsoft's suggested Registry changes](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/unable-to-change-power-settings-windows-10-even/33796242-701d-40b9-a3c2-ac277c4c96c2).

Comment: I just tried the Group Policy Editor just as you posted and tried to switch of everything with sleep. Will evaluate if it works!
Your path didnt have any CsEnabled but I found HibernateEnabledDefault and sert it to 0

Comment: The second URL, https://superuser.com/questions/1536904/windows-10-power-options-missing-on-new-laptop , has CsEnabled